# DropBox style folder storage

Tags: networking, files, directory

I would like to set up a storage for people to access. So like I have a network set up with 1 domain controller and a back up server as well and I have user accounts set up in AD and basically I want to be able to access a particular folder and sub folders and files over the internet from any where in the world. A bit like DropBox. How can I achieve this?

Any help us much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.quora.com/On-a-technical-level-how-does-Dropbox-work

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how would you suggest I set up something similar for users in AD to be able to log in from home or anywhere in the world and upload files to a certain directory on the network that they have permissions to access and read and write to?

Answer (score 2):

The [Work Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265974.aspx) feature in Windows Server 2012 R2 can do something like what you're looking for. If you're running Windows Server 2012 R2 then this feature is available to you.

Aside from that, you're looking at installing third-party software. We don't do product recommendations here, but there are any number of third-party applications, both free and commercial, that can do what you're looking for.

Edit:

Older versions of Windows support hosting files via the WebDAV protocol, and authentication can back-end into Active Directory. At that point you'd be looking at fancy client software to replicate the "Dropbox" experience.

Comment: I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: So users in AD will be able to log in from home or anywhere in the world and upload files to a certain directory on the network to a particular share that they have permissions to access and read and write to?

Comment: Sure. You serve the content using the WebDAV protocol (ideally over TLS/SSL) using IIS. IIS handles back-ending authentication back to Active Directory. Everything is stored on NTFS and users are authenticated w/ their AD credentials.

Comment: Okay and are there any security flaws in this as the data that needs to be uploaded to the server on a network is private and confidential and has to adhere to the Data Protection Act.

Comment: Can users who have domain accounts access these files remotely from home or any where else in the world and if so, what do I need to do to set it up?

Comment: @Computeristic - Access to a WebDAV site hosted by IIS can, as I said, have authentication backed by AD. This isn't a "give me t3h c0dez" site, so step-by-step instructions aren't something you're going to get here.

Comment: I totally understand where you're coming from, so could you point me in the right direction through some websites or tutorials etc please?